# How to debug warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <a> in <div>

Tags: express, url-routing, next.js, serverside-javascript, isomorphic-javascript

I am using Semantic-UI React and Next.JS but it appears at breakpoint `< 768px`, my layout completely breaks upon a refresh of the browser. I know because its a react/next.js app they are taking care of the routing but I guess I wondered what if a user happen to do that?

It doesn't happen on my `/login`, `/register` or `/profile` routes

What is strange is I've checked my files in `pages/` directory and don't see any unmatched `<a>` tags in a `</div>`

This is the Semantic-UI-component which contains the error:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
 Button,
 Container,
 Divider,
 Grid,
 Header,
 Icon,
 Image,
 List,
 Menu,
 Responsive,
 Segment,
 Sidebar,
 Visibility,
} from 'semantic-ui-react'

// Heads up!
// We using React Static to prerender our docs with server side rendering, this is a quite simple solution.
// For more advanced usage please check Responsive docs under the "Usage" section.
const getWidth = () => {
 const isSSR = typeof window === 'undefined'

 return isSSR ? Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth : window.innerWidth
}

/* eslint-disable react/no-multi-comp */
/* Heads up! HomepageHeading uses inline styling, however it's not the best practice. Use CSS or styled components for
 * such things.
 */
const HomepageHeading = ({ mobile }) => (
 <Container text>
  <Header
   as='h1'
   content='Imagine-a-Company'
   inverted
   style={{
    fontSize: mobile ? '2em' : '4em',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginTop: mobile ? '1.5em' : '3em',
   }}
  />
  <Header
   as='h2'
   content='Do whatever you want when you want to.'
   inverted
   style={{
    fontSize: mobile ? '1.5em' : '1.7em',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    marginTop: mobile ? '0.5em' : '1.5em',
   }}
  />
  <Button primary size='huge'>
   Get Started
      <Icon name='right arrow' />
  </Button>
 </Container>
)

HomepageHeading.propTypes = {
 mobile: PropTypes.bool,
}

/* Heads up!
 * Neither Semantic UI nor Semantic UI React offer a responsive navbar, however, it can be implemented easily.
 * It can be more complicated, but you can create really flexible markup.
 */
class DesktopContainer extends Component {
 state = {}

 hideFixedMenu = () => this.setState({ fixed: false })
 showFixedMenu = () => this.setState({ fixed: true })

 render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  const { fixed } = this.state

  return (
   <Responsive getWidth={getWidth} minWidth={Responsive.onlyTablet.minWidth}>
    <Visibility
     once={false}
     onBottomPassed={this.showFixedMenu}
     onBottomPassedReverse={this.hideFixedMenu}
    >
     <Segment
      inverted
      textAlign='center'
      style={{ minHeight: 700, padding: '1em 0em' }}
      vertical
     >
      <Menu
       fixed={fixed ? 'top' : null}
       inverted={!fixed}
       pointing={!fixed}
       secondary={!fixed}
       size='large'
      >
       <Container>
        <Menu.Item as='a' active>
         Home
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as='a'>Work</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as='a'>Company</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as='a'>Careers</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item position='right'>
         <Button as='a' inverted={!fixed}>
          Log in
        </Button>
         <Button as='a' inverted={!fixed} primary={fixed} style={{ marginLeft: '0.5em' }}>
          Sign Up
                  </Button>
        </Menu.Item>
       </Container>
      </Menu>
      <HomepageHeading />
     </Segment>
    </Visibility>

    {children}
   </Responsive>
  )
 }
}

DesktopContainer.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.node,
}

class MobileContainer extends Component {
 state = {}

 handleSidebarHide = () => this.setState({ sidebarOpened: false })

 handleToggle = () => this.setState({ sidebarOpened: true })

 render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  const { sidebarOpened } = this.state

  return (
   <Responsive
    as={Sidebar.Pushable}
    getWidth={getWidth}
    maxWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.maxWidth}
   >
    <Sidebar
     as={Menu}
     animation='push'
     inverted
     onHide={this.handleSidebarHide}
     vertical
     visible={sidebarOpened}
    >
     <Menu.Item as='a' active>
      Home
     </Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item as='a'>Work</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item as='a'>Company</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item as='a'>Careers</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item as='a'>Log in</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item as='a'>Sign Up</Menu.Item>
    </Sidebar>

    <Sidebar.Pusher dimmed={sidebarOpened}>
     <Segment
      inverted
      textAlign='center'
      style={{ minHeight: 350, padding: '1em 0em' }}
      vertical
     >
      <Container>
       <Menu inverted pointing secondary size='large'>
        <Menu.Item onClick={this.handleToggle}>
         <Icon name='sidebar' />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item position='right'>
         <Button as='a' inverted>
          Log in
                  </Button>
         <Button as='a' inverted style={{ marginLeft: '0.5em' }}>
          Sign Up
                  </Button>
        </Menu.Item>
       </Menu>
      </Container>
      <HomepageHeading mobile />
     </Segment>

     {children}
    </Sidebar.Pusher>
   </Responsive>
  )
 }
}

MobileContainer.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.node,
}

const ResponsiveContainer = ({ children }) => (
 <div>
  <DesktopContainer>{children}</DesktopContainer>
  <MobileContainer>{children}</MobileContainer>
 </div>
)

ResponsiveContainer.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.node,
}

const HomepageLayout = () => (
 <ResponsiveContainer>
  <Segment style={{ padding: '8em 0em' }} vertical>
   <Grid container stackable verticalAlign='middle'>
    <Grid.Row>
     <Grid.Column width={8}>
      <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
       We Help Companies and Companions
      </Header>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '1.33em' }}>
       We can give your company superpowers to do things that they never thought possible.
       Let us delight your customers and empower your needs... through pure data analytics.
      </p>
      <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
       We Make Bananas That Can Dance
            </Header>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '1.33em' }}>
       Yes that's right, you thought it was the stuff of dreams, but even bananas can be
       bioengineered.
     </p>
     </Grid.Column>
     <Grid.Column floated='right' width={6}>

     </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Row>
     <Grid.Column textAlign='center'>
      <Button size='huge'>Check Them Out</Button>
     </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
   </Grid>
  </Segment>
{/*
  <Segment style={{ padding: '0em' }} vertical>
   <Grid celled='internally' columns='equal' stackable>
    <Grid.Row textAlign='center'>
     <Grid.Column style={{ paddingBottom: '5em', paddingTop: '5em' }}>
      <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
       "What a Company"
            </Header>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '1.33em' }}>That is what they all say about us</p>
     </Grid.Column>
     <Grid.Column style={{ paddingBottom: '5em', paddingTop: '5em' }}>
      <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
       "I shouldn't have gone with their competitor."
            </Header>

     </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
   </Grid>
  </Segment> */}

  <Segment style={{ padding: '8em 0em' }} vertical>
   <Container text>
    <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
     Breaking The Grid, Grabs Your Attention
        </Header>
    <p style={{ fontSize: '1.33em' }}>
     Instead of focusing on content creation and hard work, we have learned how to master the
     art of doing nothing by providing massive amounts of whitespace and generic content that
     can seem massive, monolithic and worth your attention.
        </p>
    <Button as='a' size='large'>
     Read More
   </Button>
    <Divider
     as='h4'
     className='header'
     horizontal
     style={{ margin: '3em 0em', textTransform: 'uppercase' }}
    >
     <a href='#'>Case Studies</a>
    </Divider>

    <Header as='h3' style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>
     Did We Tell You About Our Bananas?
   </Header>
    <p style={{ fontSize: '1.33em' }}>
     Yes I know you probably disregarded the earlier boasts as non-sequitur filler content, but
     it's really true. It took years of gene splicing and combinatory DNA research, but our
     bananas can really dance.
    </p>
    <Button as='a' size='large'>
     I'm Still Quite Interested
    </Button>
   </Container>
  </Segment>

  <Segment inverted vertical style={{ padding: '5em 0em' }}>
   <Container>
    <Grid divided inverted stackable>
     <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column width={3}>
       <Header inverted as='h4' content='About' />
       <List link inverted>
        <List.Item as='a'>Sitemap</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>Contact Us</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>Religious Ceremonies</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>Gazebo Plans</List.Item>
       </List>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={3}>
       <Header inverted as='h4' content='Services' />
       <List link inverted>
        <List.Item as='a'>Banana Pre-Order</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>DNA FAQ</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>How To Access</List.Item>
        <List.Item as='a'>Favorite X-Men</List.Item>
       </List>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={7}>
       <Header as='h4' inverted>
        Footer Header
       </Header>
       <p>
        Extra space for a call to action inside the footer that could help re-engage users.
      </p>
      </Grid.Column>
     </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
   </Container>
  </Segment>
 </ResponsiveContainer>
)

export default HomepageLayout
```

What is strange its not pointing to any of my pages but spits out info regarding the library and framework?

Any help would be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get a fix for this problem @Antonio ?

Comment: @Eazy if you'd like take a look at my repo `https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder` as I think I added `<> </>` to the markup. I just don't remember when! If you can't find it ping me.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will check your repo.